# How to use django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus TimePickerInput with am/pm?

Tags: python, django, datetime, datepicker

Using django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus was super easy to set up. But using the TimePickerInput has been tricky. It defaults to 24-hour time. So I was able to change it to US am/pm time by doing this:

```
widget = TimePickerInput(format='%I:%M %p')
```

which created this strange looking but functional time picker:

[image]

My issue is at form validation. `03:39 am` is not a valid time. If I remove the am/pm from the TimePickerInput format (so dates appear like `03:39`) it validates successfully. But I obviously need to keep am/pm - which is preventing the save.

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>disposal_time<ul class="errorlist"><li>Enter a valid time.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

I've modified the clean method in the form

```
  def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(TempForm, self).clean()
        form_disposal_time = self.data.__getitem__('disposal_time')
        form_disposal_time = datetime.strptime(form_disposal_time, '%I:%M %p').time()
        cleaned_data['disposal_time'] = form_disposal_time
        return cleaned_data
```

This creates what I believe to be a valid Python time `03:39:00`. But the form still rejected it as an invalid time. And adding validation to the model is too far along in the process. I'm not sure if my clean() method is not working or if I need to intercept form validation somewhere else.
So besides moving to Europe and adopting the 24-hour clock is there any way I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify [**`input_formats`**--(Django Doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.DateField.input_formats) parameter in your [**`forms.TimeField(...)`**--(Django doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#timefield) as well.

```
from bootstrap_datepicker_plus import TimePickerInput

TIME_FORMAT = '%I:%M %p'


class FooModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    disposal_time = forms.TimeField(input_formats=[TIME_FORMAT],
                                    widget=TimePickerInput(format=TIME_FORMAT)
                                    )

    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = Foo
```

---

Django validate the value from the widget in the field level with the help of **`input_formats`** parameter. Since you are not provided any `input_formats` to the form field, Django uses the [default *time format*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-TIME_INPUT_FORMATS),

Comment: This is a great answer. The only challenge I'm running into is that I have a requirement to allow for fields to be optional. When adding this in all time fields MUST be filled. We have a requirement where blank fields actually communicate something. Is there a way to allow for optional fields with this? (I'll continue to research, but this is where I'm now at). I've got a hunch that conditional logic may be the way to go, but will have to explore.